# Problems saving Collection using ORMLite on Android

Tags: android, ormlite

I have two class:

```
public class Questionnaire {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true, useGetSet=true)
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private int type;

    @DatabaseField
    private String title;

    @DatabaseField
    private String description;


    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)   
    private Collection<Question> questions; 
// Get and Set omitted
```

and

```
  public class Question {

        @DatabaseField(generatedId=true, useGetSet=true)
        private Long id;

        @DatabaseField
        private int type;

        @DatabaseField
        private String description;


        @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh= true)
        private Questionnaire questionario;
//get and set ommited
```

When I save a Questionnaire with a List of Questions. The objects are persisted, but I lose  the relationship.

I save in this way:

```
ForeignCollection<Question> questions =
    getDao(Questionnaire.class).getEmptyForeignCollection("questions");

for(Question question : DataUtil.getAllQuestions()) {
    questions.add(question);
}

Questionnaire questionnarie = new Questionnaire();
questionnarie.setQuestions(questions);
questionnarie.setTitle("Normal");
questionnarie.setDescription("Questionário normal");
getDao(Questionnaire.class).createOrUpdate(questionarie);
```

When I retrieved this register from database, a `Question` data doesn't have a reference for `Questionnaire`, and my `Questionnaire` doesn't have question list filled.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting the `questionario` field on your `Question` objects.  The relationship is from the `Question` to the associated `Questionnaire`.  There is nothing in the `Questionnaire` table that points the other way.  See the [documentation on foreign objects](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object).

I would recommend doing something like the following:

```
Dao<Questionnaire, Long> dao = getDao(Questionnaire.class);
ForeignCollection<Question> questions =
    dao.getEmptyForeignCollection("questions");

Questionnaire questionnarie = new Questionnaire();
questionnarie.setQuestions(questions);
questionnarie.setTitle("Normal");
questionnarie.setDescription("Questionário normal");
dao.createOrUpdate(questionarie);

for(Question question : DataUtil.getAllQuestions()) {
    // you must set the questionnarie field on the Question
    // if it is a generated-id, it must be set _after_ it has been created
    question.setQuestionnaire(questionnarie);
    questions.add(question);
}
```

Comment: If my Question have another collection reference like a Collection of Option and Option have another collection.
I Have to do the same steps I did to save Questionnaire?
Is there a better way to save a Collection?